# Next.js site has favicon in chrome but not in brave

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm developing my first next.js site and I'm setting the favicon in *index.js* as follows:

```
<Head>
  <title>Create Next App</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
</Head>
```

Originally I was using a setup where my source files were all in the root directory. I now decided to move them to a `src` directory. Since then I have observed the following two weird behaviors:

1. The site has a favicon in chrome but not in brave.
2. Even if I comment out the above portion the favicon in chrome remains.

The favicon is stored in the `public` folder which is in the root directory (did not change anything about that) when moving the other files to `src`.

Comment: It's probably being cached. Have you tried opening the page in a private tab?

Comment: This worked! Thank you! If you make this an answer I can mark it as the resolution. If you know why this is happening in particular for the favicon (since the rest of the site seems not to be being cached) I would also be interested to understand that.

Comment: unfortunately I don't specifically know why that is, and it shouldn't happen if you change the file and restart your next server, but when you open the network tab you can see the HTTP status 304 instead of 200 for public assets when they are being cached, so that helps for debugging. You can disable caching by clicking on "Disable cache" at the top of your Brave/Chrome dev-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove your cache for the new route of the favicon to be recognized.

To prevent this in the future you could add a removal of the `.next` directory to remove the cache, example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
    "clean": "rm /_next && next start"
  },
```